# Read only a specified span

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, stream

I have a textfile and I want to read only a specified span from it (like position 20 to 80).

I'm using the following code, but it reads from 0 to the length of the span.

```
char[] buffer = new char[span.Length];
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
{               
    reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, span.Length);
}
```

Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
char[] buffer = new char[span.Length];
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
{    
    reader.BaseStream.Seek(span.Start, SeekOrigin.Begin); // or SeekOrigin.Current if you want to loop
    reader.Read(buffer, 0, span.Length);
}
```

Assumes the type of `span` has a `Start` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] buffer = new char[span.Length];
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
{               
    reader.ReadBlock(buffer, startIndex, span.Length);
}
```

startIndex= from where to start
span.Length = number of char's to read

Comment: But the index is the index in the destination array buffer not in the source stream. Your example code would overflow the array.

Comment: @Paul Ruane yes you are correct... but i have a question for your example.. were are you using var offset = 20; ? As I see it you are seekong the beginning off the stream

Comment: good spot. That is an artifact of an earlier revision before I realised `span` should really have the offset as a property.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried?

```
char[] buffer = new char[span.Length];
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
{               
    reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 20, span.Length);
}
```

Comment: But the index is the index in the destination array buffer not in the source stream. Your example code would overflow the array.

Comment: @Paul good catch.  That's what I get for posting without verifying.